# Applying to a Master's Program under special cirumstances

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

I know somebody who is applying to a Master's program in Computer Science. He has a learning disability and as an undergraduate, he got certain accommodations. One of then was extra time on tests.

He feels that when it comes to graduate school admissions, having a learning disability will help him get in. I think it will hurt his chances. Who is right?